# Best practice to create typed collections/lists with internal or private Add, Remove functionality?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I frequently expose typed collections and lists. Often when exposing collections and lists I am not happy with the Add and Remove methods being public. In older versions of .Net I have implemented IEnumerable but this is a lot of work.

What are the better alternatives?

I have seen questions similar to this, but not specifically about the Add / Remove accessors

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [ReadOnlyCollection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)  sove this?

**EDIT**

Since you want...

> ...to be able to add to the collection / list internally or privately

you can have a private `IList<T>` you'll be adding objects to, and the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` will be a wrapper around this list. Since it's a wrapper, all changes to an underlying list will be reflected in this read-only collection.

Comment: I would like to be able to add to the collection / list internally or privately. The ReadOnlyCollection appears to only let you construct with the final items.

Comment: +1 - I was considering keeping a reference to the list used to construct the ReadOnlyCollection. I'm pleased you already confirmed it. In this case, I have nested collections which would still make it a little awkward, but still viable. I am going to persue a base collection type with protected only add and remove methods as this would be the best solution to my current issue.

Comment: You're right, it is the correct answer. If I inherit from ReadOnlyCollection<string> and accept a List<string> as my constructor parameter, I can keep a reference in my class and also pass it to the base constructor. I can then add internal Add and Remove methods to my class. This would allow me to nest custom classes if required (instead of using string).

Answer (score 0):

Expose interface:

```
IEnumerable<T>
```